# Magento2 gallery afterLoad callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento2, fotorama

I need to move the product gallery navigation thumbnails on horizontal position if the screen is less than 768px wide.

For this I need to hook up on a callback that is triggered after the gallery is completely loaded.

How to do this when the gallery widget is initialized via the `x-magento-init` method:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]": {
            "mage/gallery/gallery": {
                ...

            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I tried adding:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'mage/gallery/gallery'], function($, gallery){
        console.log($('[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]').data('gallery'));
    });
</script>
```

And it outputs `undefined`. But when I call the same thing from the console (after the gallery was loaded) it contains the gallery object where I can call the fotorama API methods.

So how can I get the `.data('gallery')` object after the gallery is initialized ?

Many thanks!

Comment: why not use css media queries?

Comment: @madalinivascu wouldn't this be inefficient? The css is already there for the veritcal / horizontal positioning, why creating new rules ? Besides that they offers you javascript methods to change the gallery behavior. I need to learn how to access those and after that would be just a line of code.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found the solution by using the `gallery:loaded` event that is triggered after the fotorama api object is added.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'mage/gallery/gallery'], function($, gallery){
        $('[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]').on('gallery:loaded', function () {
            if($(window).width() < 768){
                $(this).on('fotorama:ready', function(){
                    var  api = $(this).data('gallery');
                    if(api.fotorama.options.navdir == 'vertical'){
                        api.fotorama.options.navdir = 'horizontal';
                        api.fotorama.resize();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Updating options with `api.updateOptions()` on `gallery:loaded` event does nothing because the options are reset after that step. So I had to hook to `fotorama:ready` event.

Comment: Your answer is working for me, but the gallery: loaded event is not working in production mode. Why this is happening? do you have any idea about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In Case anyone looking for slide end callback just use `fotorama:showend`:

```
$(this).on('fotorama:showend', function (e) {
    console.log('slide end');
 })
```